# Processing raster changes pixel value from 255 to 0

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, clip

I have a raster which I need to clip with a polygon using PyQGIS. So far it works fine, but now I came across some special cases in my source rasters where my script shows behaviour I do not understand: When one of the original raster's bands has the value "255" it is getting transformed into "0" (the info tool is showing the result of clicking on one of the darker yellow pixels):

[image]

The cut image is quite blue where the original pixels are yellow-ish (the cut raster is not visible in the screenshot above).

My snippet I use to cut the raster is:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer",
                { 'ALPHA_BAND' : True,'NODATA': None, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : rlayer, 
                'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : lyr, 'MULTITHREADING' : True, 'OPTIONS' : 'WORLDFILE=YES', 'OUTPUT' : output_r, 
                'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : "EPSG:25832", 'TARGET_CRS' : "EPSG:25832", 'X_RESOLUTION' : None,
                'Y_RESOLUTION' : None })
```

From what I understand, the algorithm "cliprasterbymasklayer" calls gdalwarp - and here must be the error, GDAL reads the 255 as "nodata" and writes it to a new "nodata" value of "0" -  how can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you try to set `NODATA` to 255 ?

Comment: won't this transform all 255 pixels into nodata pixels - which i do not want, i want them to stay 255 and not be interpreted as nodata

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the documentation right but according to me the value (255) is inserted for all nodata pixel :

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#clip-raster-by-mask-layer